# Laravel all() method on Model returning null within Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-collection

I am not sure, what is going on here. I have a collection of Model ID's but want to fallback on using all if specific ID's are omitted.

So I have this code:

```
use App\Models\Post;

function list($ids = [])
{
    $posts = collect($ids)->whenEmpty(function ($posts) {
        return Post::all()->pluck('id');
    })->each(function ($item, $key) {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($item);
    });
}
```

Works fine if I pass in specific IDs via `$ids`. But when I leave it blank `Post::all()->pluck('id');` inside of `whenEmpty()` returns empty. But if I call `Post::all()->pluck('id');` outside the collection it works just fine. So I thought it might be some sort of scoping issue since its inside a closure, but changing it to:

```
use App\Models\Post;

function list($ids = [])
{
    $posts = collect($ids)->whenEmpty(function ($posts) {
        return \App\Models\Post::all()->pluck('id');
    })->each(function ($item, $key) {
        dd($item);
    });
}
```

Is still showing up as `""` If I `dd()` the whole collection its just:

```
[
    0 => ""
]
```

So even providing the whole namespace isn't working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you really use $ids = []; for blank ids?

Comment: @Arash if you're refering to does `whenEmpty()` actually run, yes it does. That was the first thing I checked was to put `dd('here');` right before `return Post::all()->pluck('id');` to confirm the code was getting there.

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing on to the collection inside _whenEmpty_? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-whenempty. Ex. `return $posts->push(Post::all()->pluck('id'));`

Comment: Consider that in your approach you'll be querying all models twice in the case _empty_. Also instead of _each()_ consider using [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map)

Comment: @Juan Eizmendi I don't think map makes sense. I am not trying to modify the items in the collection (other than to insert all if its empty). It's just simply a list of ids that I need to iterate though to access the underlying records. Nor do I understand how it would address the extra query. But one additional query to select all shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: I think we're going to need some more info to help debug. Currently not able to reproduce this issue. I have copied/pasted your code and changed _Post_ to _User_ and worked fine for me running L 8.45.1. Can you please provide your Post DB schema and a small sample data set?

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not directly answer your question (because I would do this in a different way) but maybe it's helpful for you or others in the same situation.

What I would do is using a **Request** class to validate the introduced IDs like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Exists;

class PostsRequests extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'ids'      => ['array'],
            'ids.*'    => ['numeric', new Exists('posts','id')],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Handle a passed validation attempt.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function passedValidation()
    {
        $this->ids = $this->validated()['ids'];
    }
}
```

This way you make sure all the IDs introduced in the array exist in the posts table. Otherwise, the request fails.

Now that you know all the IDs are valid, you can simply check if the array is empty or not:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function list(PostsRequests $request)
    {
        $posts = empty($request->ids) ? Post::all() : Post::whereIn('id', $request->ids])->get();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since the array of IDs is not coming from a request, you can use a Validator in the controller itself:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Exists;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function list(array $ids)
    {
        Validator::make($ids, [
            '*' => ['numeric', new Exists('posts','id')],
        ])->validate();

        $posts = empty($ids) ? Post::all() : Post::whereIn('id', $ids])->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the ids aren't coming from a request, they are passed into the function from other code and don;t originate from the user so.....

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Then let me update my answer based on that. Anyway I prefer to validate all the inputs first and then do the necessary actions, so instead of using a Request validation you could create a simple validator

Comment: I guess I don't get why you are trying to validate it?

Comment: I think validating with `findOrFail()` when creating the collection is kind of heavy, so if you validate the ids first then you just need to check whether the array is empty or not to grab all the posts or just use the array. Imho, the validations should be done outside the controllers. My question would be "where do those ids come from". If your application "created" them someway (you performed a query, etc), they should be fine and there's no need to check them so you can just check if the array is empty. Otherwise, they should be validated on the request where the user introduced them.

Comment: They came from the app, I only did findOrFail to cover the extreme edge case of it existed when the ids were generated but was deleted since then. Granted its unlikely as the ids are generated within the same execution of the script but its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's one approach more

```
function list(array $ids = [])
{
    if(empty($ids)) $posts = Post::all(); 
    else $posts = collect($ids)->map(function($id) {
        return Post::findOrFail($id); 
    });

    $posts->each(...); /* collection */
}
```

if you want to use `whenEmpty()`

```
function list(array $ids = [])
{
    collect($ids)->map(function($id) {
        return Post::findOrFail($id);
    })->whenEmpty(function($posts){
        return $posts = Post::all();
    })->each(...);
}
```

Comment: The first block is what I already have.....that doesn't work.... The second only does work but by avoiding even using the collection.  So its a half answer. Gets around the issue of Post::all() not working even though it should.

Comment: I only put the first block for clarification, in the second part it was using a collection that just needed an extra step, I edited with one using all collection methods

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are even doing with map()

Comment: In the second block, I take all the ids, with `map()` I go throw all the ids and _transform_ each number into the correspondent model or fail, after that, either, I have a few models in the collection or an empty collection, then if it's empty `whenEmpty` it's triggered and fetch the entire set.

Comment: Yeah dosen;t make any sense why you would even try to do that but ok. I could just skip the map but then we are basically back to wehat I already have which isn't working because Post::all() isn't working inside the collection.